# On Hopfian modules over commutative Noetherian rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring with unity. Let us call an $R$-module $M$ to be Hopfian if every surjective endomorphism $M \to M $ is injective.

1) If $M_1$ and $M_2$ are Hopfian modules, then is $M_1 \oplus M_2$ necessarily Hopfian ?

2) If we have an exact sequence $0\to M_1 \to M\to M_2\to 0$  with $M$ Hopfian, then are $M_1$ and $M_2$ necessarily Hopfian ?

If these are not true in general, are there any additional conditions on $R$ that would make it true ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither is true for $R=\mathbb{Z}$ (i.e., for Hopfian abelian groups).

For (1), Corner gave an example of two Hopfian abelian grops whose direct sum is not Hopfian in

*Corner, A. L. S.*, [**Three examples on Hopficity in torsion-free Abelian groups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01904838), Acta Math. Acad. Sci. Hung. 16, 303-310 (1965). [ZBL0145.03302](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0145.03302).

(2) is easier. $\mathbb{Q}$ is a Hopfian abelian group, but has a quotient $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ which is not Hopfian, since multiplication by $n$ is surjective but not injective for any $n>1$.

Comment: thanks for your answer ... well for (2), about your example, if I'm not mistaken, any $\mathbb Z$-submodule of $\mathbb Q$ is again Hopfian right ? So can you give any example where submodule of Hopfian module is not Hopfian ?

Comment: @uno The paper https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00013-012-0402-2  contains an example of a Hopfian abelian group with a non-Hopfian subgroup, although I'm not familiar with the terminology they use. In fact the paper considers groups with the stronger property "hereditarily Hopfian", which means that every subgroup is Hopfian.